# ansible lookup not working for enviroment variables

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, lookup

Ansible lookup is not working for environment variables.

This works:

```
- name: WIN_SHELL | Get ComputerName
  win_shell: $Env:ComputerName
  register: computerName

- debug:
    var: computerName.stdout_lines.0
```

None of these do:

```
- debug:
    msg: '{{lookup("env", "ComputerName")}}'

- debug:
    msg: '{{ lookup("env", "COMPUTERNAME") }}'

- debug:
    msg: '{{ lookup("env", "computername") }}'

- debug:
    msg: '{{ lookup("env", "computerName") }}'
```

Is there something I don't understand about ansible lookup? Or is there some extenuating circumstance that's preventing this from working? I'd rather use ansible lookup than win_shell to preserve idempotence.

Comment: Are you positive that the `env` variable is set in your environment before running the playbook? Also, have you try with this module: [`win_environment`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_environment_module.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`env` as all other [lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html) is executed **on the controller machine**. In this case, this is very well recalled in the synopsis on the [documentation page for the `env` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/env.html)

> Allows you to query the environment variables available **on the controller** when you invoked Ansible.

So the `win_shell` task in your example - executed on the remote machine(s) - is absolutely not equivalent to your lookup tests - executed on the controller.

If you did not disable fact gathering on your host(s) (i.e. by setting `gather_facts: false` in your playbook), all environment variables should be accessible in the `ansible_env` dictionary. The following task should enable you to read all of them and make sure yours is set correctly (as well as getting its correct name to use it).

```yaml
- name: Debug all env vars
  debug:
    var: ansible_env
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had it switched in my head; I thought ansible_env was the environment from the controller and lookup(env, var) was the target.